# Rails - param is missing or the value is empty: user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been developing a site based on the Hartl's guide. I want to move the password reset functionality to it own partial.

I created a partial, _passreset.html.erb. Currently, it is an exact copy of _form.html.erb. I plan on editing it to only have the password fields

On the Users show.html.erb page (the profile page), I have links to Edit and Password Reset. Here is the code:

```
   <% if current_user.admin? || current_user == @user %>
   <%= link_to "Edit", edit_user_path(@user) %> | 
   <%= link_to "Password Reset", passreset_user_path(@user)%>
   <% end %>
```

When I click on the "Password Reset" link, I get the follow error: 
ActionController::ParameterMissing in UsersController#passreset
param is missing or the value is empty: user

My edit page still works perfectly.

The source of the error is my users controller params statement:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :admin)
end
```

The application trace says:

```
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:89:in `user_params'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `block in passreset'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28:in `passreset'
```

The route for the new function looks like this:

```
resources :users do
resources :articles
get 'passreset'
end
```

rake routes show these two lines, one for edit and one for passreset:

```
 edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                         users#edit
 passreset_user GET    /users/:id/passreset(.:format)                    users#passreset
```

The passreset method is (other than the notice) an exact copy of the update method.

```
 def passreset
 respond_to do |format|
  if @user.update(user_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Password was      successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status:  :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

It looks like the @user is not being passed in, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Look at `params` and figure out what's in there. It isn't what you expect. You can see this in the log and interactively using `byebug`. This is trivially easy to debug, given the tooling that comes with Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`passreset_user_path(@user)` doesn't "pass in" user to the method in question, it generates a URL. The URL will include an ID segment. It will look something like this:

```
/users/123/passreset
```

Your action will be invoked with the ID segment available in `params[:id]`. It's up to you to find the corresponding user in the database.

Instead of relying on `params[:user]`, you need to do something along the lines of `@user = User.find(params[:id])`

The larger issue is that your `passreset` action makes no sense. It appears to be setup to receive a POST request containing new attributes for the user, but you're linking to it with a button that will produce a GET request with no payload of user attributes.

You're missing an entire intermediate step, where you show the user a password reset form. Your first request needs to serve that form up, and then that form can POST back to your `passreset` method.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you. I simply removed the content of the passreset action, and it worked immediately.